# what is the best way to removing duplicate records from a file of 10 terabyte size?

Tags: oracle, algorithm, sorting, oracle11g

what is the best way to removing duplicate records from a file of 10 terabyte size?

to be specific I'm using oracle 11g. each record consists of 20 fields of varchar(255)(60)etc ,Date, or Number. about 10% of records are duplicate , duplication can be recognized by a field of 10digit number.
order does'nt matter but I appreciate if you could mention what should I do in case of ordering, I have a core2dou CPU with 4gb RAM.

Comment: Where are stocked those tera?

Comment: What kind of file and what kind of records ? Please be more specific.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information before this can be answered.

Comment: Size of records?  Proportion of duplicates?  Does the order of the remaining records matter?  How much memory do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [element distinctness Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), that can be solved by these two approaches:

1. Sort (External sort in your case) and iterate: First sort your file, and then iterate it, all duplicate entries will be adjacent to each other.
2. Use hash table to store elements that are identical. Since the hashtable cannot fit in memory (and implementing it on disk is inefficient), you could do it in chunks, first load into RAM all entries (and hashes) whom hash code is in range `[0,a)`, and write all unique elements to a new file. Then repeat for range `[a,b)`, `[b,c)`, ... .... Make sure the ranges are enough to contain all elements in that range. Note that you can do it recursively (i.e. write a mid file with hash `[x,y]`, and recursively invoke on this new file to screen duplicates. It makes this approach need `O(nlogn)` disk accesses for very large files.

A distributed version of the 2nd approach is to use [map-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce):

```
map(file):
   emit(key,'1')
reduce(key,list):
   emit(key)
```